# Firefox - The operation is insecure [toDataURL]

Tags: firefox, localhost, todataurl

I'm running a local website under Wamp and I would like to open a local file inside a canvas, edit it through filters, and save it back again in local.

However, when I try to use .toDataURL() on my edited canvas, Firefox throws "The operation is insecure".

I have full control over the computer and I would like to "bypass" this security check as Firefox is running in fullscreen mode. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using [CamanJS](http://camanjs.com/) for manipulating canvas and exporting data.

Weirdly, it works with this plugin.